# Time it takes for a gas to go to the equator

Tags: greenhouse-gases, transportation

The question is the following:

In order to understand the sources and sinks of greenhouse gases we need to understand their transport, both vertically and horizontally.  It takes _______ time for a gas to travel from Boston to Tokyo, Japan than from Boston to just over the equator.

with the options being more/less/same. I think the answer should be more since the distance is less (by quite a bit apparently). However, I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct there.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is this homework? You should show some effort if you wish an answer here. Ennunciate only homework questions are not allowed

Comment: For this you need to consider how air moves in the atmosphere. Consider the jet stream & Hadley cells & other atmospheric currents

Comment: Not a homework question. Just came across it, and was curious. I'm a Computer Science guy, but am looking to learn about climate change

Comment: This video: https://youtu.be/MaXDrLOhI_A will help you understand atmospheric circulation

Comment: please take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadley_cell and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_stream and you might find this helpful https://earth.nullschool.net/#current/wind/surface/level/orthographic=-62.42,1.42,424 the last link will show you how the wind moves at different elevations and you can even find how polution moves around the world.if you use this information you will be able to edit your question and make it a lot more spesific.